# Need help with self study on surds

Tags: exponentiation

give x in the form A $ \sqrt B$ + C

$(\sqrt 3x) = 3$

can someone show me how to solve this please?

Comment: Since $3 = \sqrt{3} \sqrt{3}$, divide both sides by $\sqrt{3}$ to get $x=\sqrt{3}$. Is this OK or do you need more ?

Comment: I understand now thanks for explaining it to me.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   (√3x) = 3
=> 3x^2 = 9     {Squaring both sides}
=> x^2 = 9/3
=> x^2 = 3
=> x = +√3 or -√3 {as square of a positive or negative number will be a positive no. so using the converse of this fact ie square root of a number may be positive or may be negative but not both.}
```

Now, the Answer will be x = √3 as this satisfies the equation (√3x) = 3 when x value is substituted as √3.